# realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread (with ReactiveSwift)

Tags: swift, realm, reactive-swift

I have a view model that's fetching some data from my API, and when I get data back, I'm setting it both in Realm and on two MutableProperties on the view model

```
        userService.getBrowseData().on(
            failed: { error in
                // TODO: Should call a closure the VC passes in here with an error to show
            }, value: { banners, lists in
                browseStoreService.store(banners: banners, lists: lists)

                self.banners.value = banners
                self.lists.value = lists
            }
        ).startWithCompleted { self.dataLoaded.value = true }
```

In my view controller, I'm getting a crash at the line where I instantiate and set a `ListViewViewModel`

```
disposable += viewModel?.dataLoaded.producer
    .observe(on: UIScheduler())
    .startWithValues { loaded in
        if loaded {
            guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return }

            self.carousel?.reloadData()

            for list in viewModel.lists.value {
                let view = ListView()
                view.viewModel = ListViewViewModel(list: list)
                view.listViewDelegate = self
                view.listItemViewDelegate = self

                scrollingStackView.addArrangedSubview(view: view)

                constrain(view) { view in
                    view.width == view.superview!.width
                    view.left == view.superview!.left
                    view.right == view.superview!.right
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The strange thing to me is that I'm just setting the data in realm, I'm not doing any additional fetch to get the data out of realm which would make sense to cause a crash, especially if the write hadn't finished.

In this case, I'm taking an array of `banners` and an array of `lists` in my response from the API, sending them into my `storeService` to set them in realm and assigning those same arrays to their respective MutableProperties.

Any idea what could be going here that would be causing this crash?

Edit:

The `store` function looks like this:

```
func store(banners: [Banner], lists: [List]) {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(banners, update: true)
                realm.add(lists, update: true)
            }
        } catch {
            return
        }

        realm.refresh()
    }
```

and both models have a primary key of `id`

Comment: I found a fix by doing the Realm write on the main thread. Not sure if there's a better way to solve this but that's one solution

Comment: Even if it's just reading the properties, you cannot access Realm objects across threads. If it works on the main thread, that implies you must be storing a reference to a Realm object that was originally created on the main thread. You should be able to set an exception breakpoint to track the exact line of code that's causing the exception and see which Realm object is causing the issue.

Comment: Additionally, if you're not using it already, it might be worth checking out RxRealm (https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm) for integrating Realm into reactive UIs this way. :)

Comment: I use ReactiveSwift, not RxSwift